# Android how to add intellisense in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm using Android.I want to add suggestions on the editText when user write something it should How can I add intelliSense in  editText?

Comment: Please try this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use AutocompleteTextView 
Read this tutorial.I'm sure it will solve your problem.
http://www.javatpoint.com/android-autocompletetextview-example

Answer (score 0):

You should use

> AutoCompleteTextView

Here is a short tutorial to implement this widget, which is working like a TextView, but with an adapter http://www.androidaspect.com/2012/06/autocompletetextview-example.html